# Buildsteps after each other

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I run several buildsteps after each other in IntelliJ? I think I want a mini CI/CD build system inside the editor.

For example, the project I work on now is a Spring boot and javascript web site. I need to build it with maven with `mvn clean package -Pdockerimage`. This copies files for building the Docker image to target/dockerimgbuild.

Then I want to build the docker image using `docker build -t scheduling-ui-dev .` and after that run it with docker compose `docker-compose up --build` from src/main/resources/docker-compose.

I have built one run configuration for each of these steps but how do I run them after each other? I have found that you can have before launch but the system is clunky and complains if target/dockerimgbuild doesn't exists even before it have run the maven step which creates it. Latest problem I stumbled on was that a file prevented maven from removing target/dockerimgbuild and all run steps was automatically removed from the run configurations.

There is a run configuration called compound but that runs everything in parallell and you can not specify order which is a problem.

I wonder if it is feasible to start TeamCity in a container, do anyone have a clue about that (is teamcity easy to configure, how to make it launch a docker-compose container on my host machine etc)?

My solution right now is to have several terminals (if this gets more permanent I will replace it with a script) where I just press up and enter to execute the steps manually. Seems stupid as I guess maven itself can do all of this...but I don't know how or how much work it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a compound Run/Debug configuration: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-compound-run-configuration.html
Also, there is a multi-run plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248-multirun

Comment: Compound is not really what I am looking for since the tasks must be independent from each other (you cannot change the run order as all tasks runs at the same time). The Multi-run plugin however is something that does what I am looking for. I did a script before looking at your answer but I will try it out!